# Unity2D predictive bow aiming using object array only displaying vertically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a bow and arrow game in Unity2D, and I want to use an Angry Birds style predictive aiming system(like in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Jqy.png).

I have loosely followed a tutorial, but for whatever reason, in my game, it only predicts on the vertical axis. The code works by initializing GameObjects and placing them in a list. Here is the code:

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < Points.Length; i++) {
    Points[i].transform.position = PointPosition(i * time);          
}
```

```cs
Vector2 PointPosition(float t) {
    Vector2 currentPointPos = (Vector2)transform.position + ((direction.normalized * force * t) * 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * (t*t));
    return currentPointPos;
}
```

The way I understood it, by using the `+` operand on `transform.position` it would add to both axis'. Am I wrong about this? Do I need to do two operations for both axis'? Or is my error somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the gravity to the initial velocity. (You multiply it which is wrong)

```
var v0 = direction.normalized * force;
var delta = new Vector2(0, 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * t);
var offset = (v0 + delta) * t;
Vector2 currentPointPos = (Vector2)transform.position + offset;
```